Как подключить яндекс карты api v3 к приложени на vue3?
документация дает примеры, см закладку vue.html для случая загрузки vue через CDN. в частности, там присуствует код, который обращается к глобальному экземпляру Vue
const vuefy = ymaps3Vue.vuefy.bindTo(Vue);

этот экземпляр есть только в CDN сборках vue и отсутствует, если собирать приложение с помощью vite и подключать vue через package.json. как быть в таком случае?

Тоже столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Не разбирался еще, как подключить через vite, но смог подключить через CDN!
Эту мистическую переменную Vue можно получить следующим образом:
import * as Vue from 'vue';

Но для корректной работы, вероятно, придется добавить в vite.config следующий alias:
resolve: {
    alias: {
        vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js'
    }
},

